# Creating delay between shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making shooting system for my game on Unity(c#)
here is the code:

```
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform shotPoint;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to make a delay between shooting, so can someone made a float delay between shooting?`

Answer (score 0):

**I personally feel** the simplest way to achieve this is to use a **coroutine**.

```
bool canShoot = true;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot)
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        StartCoroutine(ShotTimer());
    }
}

Ienumerator ShotTimer()
{
  canShoot = false;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(**time to wait between shots**);
  canShoot = true;
}
```

Comment: You are inside an `Update()` call where you have access to `DeltaTime`. Why are you overcomplicating things with a CoRoutine where it is not needed? This is not simple at all, it's absolute overkill!

Comment: @TheNomad be fair .. this is one valid approach  yours is another .. and tbh it can still be [more simple than that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036758/7111561) ;) there is no need to keep track of a timer except you really want to visualize it

Comment: @derHugo I totally agree. My issue was with the caption that it is "the simplest" way.

Comment: @TheNomad I personally feel that instead of manually having to manage the deduction and resetting of the timer, simply having "WaitForSeconds" is far simpler to use. I certainly don't appreciate being attacked for presenting a perfectly valid approach to the problem that's been raised.

Comment: @TheG Where's the attack? Let's not get into a 10 year-old victimization chat. I can understand how you thought this is easier, but you need to understand, to someone that doesn't know C# or Unity, this can't be easier, since latent functions (and even the ability to call anonymous functions) can't be something easy to comprehend. On SO, answers are often challenged. If you find this "an attack", you won't fit here, sorry. There is not attack, there is no offense, it is simply not "simple" if you allow the pun. Just say "One way to do it is..." and we're fine.

Comment: Going across multiple of my answers informing me I have a "fetish" for co routines absolutely is an attack, as is snarkily referencing my answer in your own. You can deliver criticism and thought-provoking discussion without being rude. You keep bringing up "fitting in". I don't need to fit in. I bring my own thoughts and opinions to the table as everyone else should, and in this case it is my opinion that this is the simplest approach for resolving the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you will hear from others, **do not** use a coroutine, unless you really have to. It's completely overkill and will overcomplicate your code.

```
public class YourWeaponClassOrWhatever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet; 
    public Transform shotPoint;
    public float shootingPause; // this is what you set in the editor's Inspector
    private float shootingTime = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && (shootingTime <= 0.0f))
        {
            shootingTime = shootingPause;
            Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        if (shootingTime > 0.0f)
            shootingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a simple check whether the time defined by `cooldown` has passed since the last shot was fired:

```
public GameObject bullet;
public Transform shotPoint;
public float cooldown = 1f; // configured desired delay in Inspector

private float lastShootTime;

void Start()
{
    // to be able to shoot right away when the app started 
    lastShootTime = -cooldown;
}

void Update()
{
    // is the current time at least cooldown seconds bigger than when the last bullet was shot?
    if (Time.unscaledTime - lastShootTime >= cooldown && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        // Time.unscaledTime is the current time in seconds since app-start 
        lastShootTime = Time.unscaledTime;
    }
}
```

---

Or another approach similar to the Coroutine but without a continous execution but rather using Unity's message system you can use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```
public GameObject bullet;
public Transform shotPoint;
public float cooldown = 1f; // configured desired delay in Inspector

private bool canShoot;

void Update()
{
    if(canShoot && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        // Time.unscaledTime is the current time in seconds since app-start 
        canShoot = false;
        Invoke(nameof(EnableShoot), cooldown);
    }
}

private void EnableShoot()
{
    canShoot = true;
}
```

---

There are many different ways - it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. You can either use a Coroutine or an Update function.

**Using Coroutine**

```
public GameObject bullet_Prefab; 
public Transform shotPoint;
public float shootingDelay; 
private bool canShoot = true;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot)
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
     //Shoot logic
     Instantiate(bullet_Prefab, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);

     StartCoroutine(coroutine_ShootDelay());
}

IEnumerator coroutine_ShootDelay()
{
    canShoot = false;
    yeild return new WaitForSeconds(shootingDelay);
    canShoot = true;
}
```

**Using Update**

```
public GameObject bullet_Prefab; 
public Transform shotPoint;
public float shootingDelay; 

private float shootDelayRemaining;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && shootDelayRemaining<= 0f)
    {
        shootDelayRemaining = shootingDelay;
        Shoot();
    }

    if (shootDelayRemaining > 0f)
    {
        shootDelayRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
     //Shoot logic
     Instantiate(bullet_Prefab, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

There may be some other weird ways to achieve this. But these two are the best ones you can use. Use whichever you feel is cleaner and easier to understand